# Method of determining symmetries in an irregular polygon (2D or 3D)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, symmetry, reflection

Thank you in advance for helping.

Given a polygon with $n$ vertices, $$P = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} & x_{2} & ... & x_{n} \\ y_{1} & y_{2} & ... & y_{n} \end{bmatrix}$$ how does one determine:

1) The axes of symmetry, if there are any

2) Radial (rotational) symmetry, if it exists

3) Any other type of symmetry (or something $close$ to a symmetry, if such a thing exists)

Methods involving linear algebra and/or group theory are more than welcome.

And if you can suggest, any thoughts for finding symmetries in three-dimensional polygons? (Not sure what they're called...) $$P = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} & x_{2} & ... & x_{n} \\ y_{1} & y_{2} & ... & y_{n} \\ z_{1} & z_{2} & ... & z_{n} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: In three dimensions they're called polyhedrons, in four dimensions polychorons, and beyond that just polytopes.

Comment: Three-dimensional polygon-analogs are called *polyhedra*, and *polytopes* for a generic dimension-free word. My first thought would be to compute the centroid and group vertices by how far from the centroid they are; these groups of vertices must be preserved by any symmetries. Any bounded region of $\Bbb R^2$ must have either cyclic or dihedral symmetry, to narrow things down.

Comment: @psj36 what result are you quoting in classifying the symmetry groups of bounded regions, and how does it apply, say, to a closed disc?

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah, yes, I forgot to mention that those are the only *finite* symmetry groups, thank you! I suppose I had the classification of finite subgroups of $O_2(\Bbb R)$ in mind, affectionately called (by Weyl, or maybe Weil...) *Leonardo's Theorem*.

Answer (score 1):

An invertible affine map  is a symmetry of the polygon iff it permutes the vertices.  Three non-collinear vertices will be enough to determine the map.  It's convenient to use homogeneous coordinates, so the vertices are represented as $\pmatrix{x_i\cr y_i\cr 1\cr}$ and the transformation is multiplication by  a $3 \times 3$ matrix with last row $[ 0\; 0\; 1]$.
Then the transformation that takes a given three vertices $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ to another three vertices $v'_1$, $v'_2$, $v'_3$ can be found as
the matrix $V' V^{-1}$, where $V$ is the matrix formed from the columns corresponding to $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and $V'$ the matrix formed from the columns
corresponding to $v'_1, v'_2, v'_3$.